# Не могу получить position первой страницы ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Сделал  реализацию ViewPager для перелистывания слайдов, все работает нормально. Проблема с OnPageChangeListener() - при первом показе первой страницы он не "слышит" position этой страницы. Соответственно, не может начать воспроизведение файла mp3 при нажатии ToggleButton. Адаптер при этом работает нормально, показывает первую страницу.

Если листаю право и потом возвращаюсь назад на первую страницу - все хорошо, позицию возвращает. Подскажите, как можно справиться с этим?

```
public class SliderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHome);
        View.OnClickListener clickHome = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                GoHome();
            }
        };

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(clickHome);
/*
 * Читаем json и создаем из него объект книги bookFiles
 */
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int bookId = GetBookId();
        String fileName = "book_" + bookId + ".json";
        String gsResult = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileName);
        BookFiles bookFiles = gson.fromJson(gsResult, BookFiles.class);

        final String folderB = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
        /*
        Получаем из объекта bookFiles массивы путей к файлам книги
         */
        ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = bookFiles.getPagesPath();
        final ArrayList<String> soundsFiles = bookFiles.getSoundsPath();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, pagesFiles);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlay);

        //слушаем номер слайда при перелистывании
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
                if(mp != null){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                getMedia(nameS, folderB);
                toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(SliderActivity.this);

                if (toggleButton.isChecked()){
                    mp.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    public int GetBookId() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookId", 1);
        return bookId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) mp.start();
        else if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        }

    }

    public void getMedia(String nameS, String folderB) {
        final String soundPath = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(folderB));
        final Uri souF = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath, nameS));
        final MediaPlayer mp = MyPlayer.getMp(getApplicationContext(), souF);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    private void GoHome() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SliderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 10);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая проблема, да. Выход - выделение слушателя в отельную переменную и ручное вызывание кол-бэка на 0 элементе:

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //тут код
    }
});

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener)

listener.onPageSelected(0);
```