# Проблема автоматического перелистывания страниц ViewPager на первой странице

Tags: android, android-viewpager

При использовании ViewPager есть проблема определения позиции первой страницы. Обошел ее, используя это [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762471/259287). Это не дубль!! Просто решение этой проблемы более правильное.
Теперь нужно сделать автоматическое перелистывание страниц после завершения воспроизведения mp3, и не могу сообразить - как автоматически уйти с первой страницы ViewPager. Начиная со второй страницы все работает как надо. Подскажите способ решить эту проблему.

Вот код

```
public class SliderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHome);
        View.OnClickListener clickHome = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                GoHome();
            }
        };

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(clickHome);
/*
 * Читаем json и создаем из него объект книги bookFiles
 */
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int bookId = GetBookId();
        String fileName = "book_" + bookId + ".json";
        String gsResult = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileName);
        BookFiles bookFiles = gson.fromJson(gsResult, BookFiles.class);

        final String folderB = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
        /*
        Получаем из объекта bookFiles массивы путей к файлам книги
         */
        ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = bookFiles.getPagesPath();
        final ArrayList<String> soundsFiles = bookFiles.getSoundsPath();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, pagesFiles);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlay);

        //слушаем номер слайда при перелистывании
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
                if(mp != null){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                getMedia(nameS, folderB);
                toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(SliderActivity.this);

                if (toggleButton.isChecked()){
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
                String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
                if(mp != null){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                getMedia(nameS, folderB);
                toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(SliderActivity.this);

                if (toggleButton.isChecked()){
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        int pagen = position+1;
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagen, true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);

        listener.onPageSelected(0);

    }

    public int GetBookId() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookId", 1);
        return bookId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) mp.start();
        else if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        }

    }

    public void getMedia(String nameS, String folderB) {
        try {
            final String soundPath = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(folderB));
            final Uri souF = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath, nameS));
            final MediaPlayer mp = MyPlayer.getMp(getApplicationContext(), souF);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void GoHome() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SliderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 10);
    }

}
```

Comment: так у вас такой же вопрос уже задан

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перелистывать ViewPager программно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777522/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-viewpager-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Нет, дело в том, что программно перелистывать я могу - но не с первой страницы... Именно на первой позиции не срабатывает. Это какой-то баг ViewPager

Comment: ну а куда хотите листать с первой страницы? Я осмневаюсь что в таком простом месте мб баг во ViewPager

Comment: на следующую, поэтому в коде прибавляю к position +1

Comment: так у вас в коде viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true); вы просто всегда скролиет ко 2-й странице.

Comment: проблема определить позицию первой страницы придумана не мной, есть ссылки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72455/discussion-between--and-shwarz-andrei).

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: решение найдено

Answer (score 1):

Нашел такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675705) - ввести переменную, при проверке которой будет инициализироваться слушатель ViewPager-а. При этом код упрощается.

```
    //слушаем номер слайда при перелистывании
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        Boolean first = true;
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (first && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0){
                onPageSelected(0);
                first = false;
            }
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                int pagen = position+1;
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagen, true);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
            if(mp != null){
                mp.stop();
            }
            getMedia(nameS, folderB);
            toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(SliderActivity.this);

            if (toggleButton.isChecked()){
                mp.start();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```